# how to delete angular.js v 1.3 cookies on tab close

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

i want to delete cookies in angular.js on tab close.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {       
            delete $cookies["Email"];
            delete $cookies["isLoggedIn"];
            delete $cookies["Token"];
            delete $cookies["Name"];    
            delete $cookies["LogCode"];
        });
```

i have called this function in app.js but it doesn't work. can you suggest me regarding  this issue.
please note: i am using angular.js version 1.3

Comment: I think this is not the way to remove cookies, it removes properties from the object. Have you tried `$cookies.remove(key)`, as described in [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)?

Comment: sorry $cookies.remove(key) is not working, i use delete $cookies["key"]; to delete cookies on LogOut function and it s also working

Comment: instead of using cookies, try sessionstorage- it's automatically clears after closing tab/ browser

Comment: $(window).on('onunload', function() { 
    $cookies.remove(Email);
    $cookies.remove(isLoggedIn);
    $cookies.remove(Token);
    $cookies.remove(Name);
    $cookies.remove(LogCode);
      
   });
is this code is in right format?

Comment: Cookie name should be in quotes. BTW, why not call your `logout()` method in the `beforeunload` callback?

Comment: $scope.logOut = function() {   
  delete $cookies["Name"];
  delete $cookies["Email"];
  delete $cookies["isLoggedIn"];
  delete $cookies["Token"];
  delete $cookies["Name"];
  delete $cookies["LogCode"];
  $scope.isLoggedIn = null;
  window.location.reload();
    };
 
 
 $(window).on('onunload', function() { 
    $scope.logOut();
      
   });
.......i called it like that ...is it right?

Comment: Yes, but I thought maybe your logout function does something more than that, cause now it's the same as in your original question. Does your `beforeunload` callback execute at all?

Comment: yes, when i return 'hello' it beforeunload function is working and also reply to page a alert "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved" on refresh page. but cookies are still working @llya Luzyanim

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

//Handle page refresh and tab close

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function(){

        $cookies.remove('Email');
        $cookies.remove('isLoggedIn');
        //Delete rest of the cookies similarly

};
```